# Responsive Grid layout issue with Dynamic content (issue with IE 11 only)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 beta and came across layout problem while generating Dynamic contents for Responsive Grid. All browser seems working fine except IE 11 (Edge work just fine).

If i keep Layout static, [everything looks smooth as shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Qy6.jpg) and here is 
[bootply code](https://www.bootply.com/84x1JkEjfj).

Now if i change it to dynamically generate data and fill in div, it start giving me problem in layout [IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE2pm.jpg) and here is [bootply code](https://www.bootply.com/x9B36BT3QD).

Every thing is working just fine in Firefox, Chrome and Edge but only start showing issue with IE 11.

*Adding code sample, you can save these files as html and test in IE11 and you will see the problem.*

**Static Code sample**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <script>
        function openWindow()
        {
            $('#myModal').modal({show:true})
        }
        </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>     
</head>
<body>
    <a class="btn btn-default" id="openBtn" href="#" onclick="openWindow();">Open modal</a>

    <div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4 class="g-mb-10 g-color-primary g-font-weight-600 text-capitalize">Company Name INC. <span class="h5 g-color-black">123343244</span></h4><div><div class="row"><div class="col-xl-12 col-xs-12 g-mb-15"><ul class="list-unstyled g-color-gray-dark-v5 g-font-size-13"><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-hotel-restaurant-235 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">68 SOME AREA ST, QUEENS, NY, 11345 - 6345, United States</div></li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-001 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">http://www.microsoft.com</div></li></ul></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12 g-mb-5"><ul class="list-unstyled g-color-gray-dark-v5 g-font-size-13"><li class="g-color-black g-font-weight-600 text-capitalize">Bill CLINTON</li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-033 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">800 852 3543</div></li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-155 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">800 852 3543</div></li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-062 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">support@microsoft.com</div></li></ul></div><div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12 g-mb-5"><ul class="list-unstyled g-color-gray-dark-v5 g-font-size-13"><li class="g-color-black g-font-weight-600 text-capitalize">Bill CLINTON</li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-033 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">800 852 3543 ext 205</div></li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-155 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">800 852 3543</div></li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-062 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">support@microsoft.com</div></li></ul></div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<body>
</html>
```

**Dynamic Code sample**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <script>
        function openWindow()
        {
          $('#innerData').html('<h4 class="g-mb-10 g-color-primary g-font-weight-600 text-capitalize">Company Name INC. <span class="h5 g-color-black">123343244</span></h4><div><div class="row"><div class="col-xl-12 col-xs-12 g-mb-15"><ul class="list-unstyled g-color-gray-dark-v5 g-font-size-13"><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-hotel-restaurant-235 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">68 SOME AREA ST, QUEENS, NY, 11345 - 6345, United States</div></li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-001 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">http://www.microsoft.com</div></li></ul></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12 g-mb-5"><ul class="list-unstyled g-color-gray-dark-v5 g-font-size-13"><li class="g-color-black g-font-weight-600 text-capitalize">Bill CLINTON</li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-033 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">800 852 3543</div></li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-155 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">800 852 3543</div></li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-062 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">support@microsoft.com</div></li></ul></div><div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12 g-mb-5"><ul class="list-unstyled g-color-gray-dark-v5 g-font-size-13"><li class="g-color-black g-font-weight-600 text-capitalize">Bill CLINTON</li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-033 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">800 852 3543 ext 205</div></li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-155 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">800 852 3543</div></li><li class="media"><i class="d-flex mt-1 mr-3 icon-communication-062 u-line-icon-pro"></i><div class="media-body">support@microsoft.com</div></li></ul></div></div></div>');

            $('#myModal').modal({show:true})
        }
        </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>     
</head>
<body>
    <a class="btn btn-default" id="openBtn" href="#" onclick="openWindow();">Open modal</a>

    <div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <label id="innerData"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are required to post a complete and minimal example of your markup that shows the problem here, not any other third party service which can change or disappear tomorrow, helping no one in the future: [mcve] It should contain a clear description of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after finding no help on anywhere i kind of figured out by debugging css line by line.
Once added this in header problem goes away (at least for IE11, which was my primary concern)

```
<style>
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
     .inblock_issue{display:block;}
}   
</style>
```

And don't forget to add class "inblock_issue" to div.